# How can I attach a datarule to a data broker's key-generation operation?

Tags: aviarc

I have a Workflow SQL databroker in which the ID field is a sequential number with additional character padding, i.e. **P001** or **TM234**.

I have defined the query for ID generation as:

```
<key-generation field="id" query="queries/asset-patent-get-id" />
```

which simply retrieves next sequence value based on provided parameters. So for every created record I need to make sure that by the time ID gets stored in database it was already padded as per required rules and stored as a string rather than just a number.

Comment: Why isn't the key-generation query returning the ID in the proper format?

Comment: @TristanWilkinson It could, but I just wanted the business rules to be done on the application's side rather than in DB.

Comment: I think you want to have a datarule which generates the key before the dataset is committed then, rather than a datarule which adjusts the key on key-generation which happens as part of commit - I'm not sure if there's any chance for rules to kick in at that point. Something based on the onBeforeDatasetPersisted event maybe?

Comment: @TristanWilkinson Well, based on the description of the Persistence operations order [see here](http://dev.aviarc.com/docs/aviarc/dev_guide/workflow_sql_broker) I would expect that key generation routine would be performed prior to the create routine, and I assume this would include the data rules binding. But I might be wrong on that one.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note: a data rule isn't bound to an *operation,* but instead to a *field.* So in this case, just think of the key-generation operation as retrieving the next number in a sequence, nothing more. Once the sequence value is retrieved, an appropriate bound data rule should be able to format the sequence value before it is persisted.

You should be able to define a data rule something like this:

```xml
<!-- datarules/format-asset-patent-id/definition.xml -->
<data-rule name="format-asset-patent-id"
           factory-class="com.aviarc.framework.datarule.xml.DefaultXMLDataRuleProviderFactoryImpl"
           datarule-class="com.aviarc.framework.datarule.workflow.WorkflowDataRule">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="field" mandatory="y"/>
    </parameters>
    <event name="onBeforeDatasetPersisted" workflow="workflows/format-asset-patent-id" field="{@field}"/>
</data-rule>
```

Then in the format-asset-patent-id workflow you can take care of formatting the id. (**Note:** I haven't had the chance to test whether the onBeforeDatasetPersisted event fires before or after the key-generation operation is performed.)

Then you could bind it with a data binding, for example:

```xml
<!-- databindings/asset-patent.xml -->
<databinding databroker="asset-patent"
             factory-class="com.aviarc.framework.databinding.basic.BasicDataBindingFactoryImpl">
    <on-dataset-bound>
        <data-rules>
            <format-asset-patent-id field="id"/>
        </data-rules>
    </on-dataset-bound>
</databinding>
```